# mixitup show div based on filter selection after mixEnd

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, mixitup

I am using the jQuery plugin MixItUp to have a filterable grid of products.

I know there are [callback functions](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#group-callbacks) for what I want to do but I don't know how to use it.

Code looks like this:

```
<ul id="product-filters" class="list-filter list-inline">
    <li class="filter active" data-filter="all"><span>All</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-1" data-filtername="category-1"><span>Category 1</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-2" data-filtername="category-2"><span>Category 2</span></li>
</ul>

<div id="description-category-1" class="term-description hidden">
    <p>Term description for category 1 here...</p>
</div>
<div id="description-category-2" class="term-description hidden">
    <p>Term description for category 2 here...</p>
</div>

<div id="grid">
<!-- Products .mix here... -->
</div>
```

And this is the js:

```
$('#grid').mixItUp({
    animation: {animateResizeContainer: true, animateChangeLayout: true},
    selectors: {target: '.mix', filter: '.filter'}
});
```

What I want to achieve is that `#description-category-1` is being shown when the `.filter` with `data-filter=".category-1"` is clicked and that it's hidden again when another filter is selected.

How do you get the selected filter in MixItUp?
And how do you construct a callback function which does the above?

Answer (score 0):

For use **callback** you can do the following :

```
    $('#grid').mixItUp({
      callbacks: {
         onMixLoad: function (state) {
            alert('MixItUp ready!');
         },
         onMixStart: function (state, futureState) {
            alert('Animation starting');
         },
         onMixEnd: function (state) {
            alert('Operation ended');
         },
         onMixFail: function(state){
            alert('No elements found matching '+state.activeFilter);
         },
         onMixBusy: function (state) {
            alert('MixItUp busy');
         }
      }
   });
```

callback must be written as object `callbacks: {....}`.
Or you can **Binding** a the **event** using jQuery's `.on()` method :

```
$('#grid').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
    //do something 
});
```

First argument of all callback functions contains useful information about the current filter and sort state. (it is also available via the `getState` API method) 
**[for more information see](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#state-object)**

**For Example :**

```
 $('#grid').mixItUp({
    callbacks: {
        onMixStart: function (state, futureState) {
            console.log(state.activeFilter)
        }
    }
});
```

`state.activeFilter` represent the active filter string, object or function.
with if statement in callbacks function , you can get filter name and ....

```
 if(state.activeFilter=="myDesiredFilter"){
     //do something\
 }
```